# Create wrapper to return particular values from an already existing function

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I have a function called

```
tfnet.return_predict()
```

which when run on an image outputs certain set o values such as the class of object confidence and coordinates of bounding box. What i want to do is make a wrapper which returns only the confidence value.

So my code is as follows. I am using Darkflow to perform Prediction of classes on images.

```
#Initialise Libraries
# Load the YOLO Neural Network

tfnet = TFNet(options) #call the YOLO network 
image = cv2.imread('C:/darkflow/Car.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  #Load image
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

print(tfnet.return_predict(image)) #function to run predictions
```

The output of print is

```
[{'label': 'Car', 'confidence': 0.32647023, 'topleft': {'x': 98, 'y': 249}, 'bottomright': {'x': 311, 'y': 455}}]
```

So from this i want to create a wrapper which just returns the 'confidence' value.

I know how to create wrappers and define functions for it but how to do it for already defined functions.

Any suggestion is of great help to mee

EDIT: I tried:

```
def log_calls(tfnet.return_predict):
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    #name = func.__name__
    print('before {name} was called')
    r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    print('after {name} was called')
    return r
return wrapper
```

But the 'tfnet.return_predict' is returning error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to redefine the `tfnet.return_predict` function to only return confidence? Or is having a separate function okay? If it's the latter, then it seems like you can just do this:

```py
def conf_only(*args, **kwargs):
    out = tfnet.return_predict(*args, **kwargs)
    return out[0]["confidence"]
```

and calling `conf_only` returns just that part of the dict.

If you need to have tfnet.return_predict redefined and want that to only return `confidence`, then you can make a decorator:

```py
def conf_deco(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)[0]["confidence"]
    return wrapper
```

For example, pretending `dummy_function` is already predefined

```
def dummy_function(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    return [{"confidence": .32, "other": "asdf"}]
```

```
In [4]: dummy_function("something", kw='else')
('something',) {'kw': 'else'}
Out[4]: [{'confidence': 0.32, 'other': 'asdf'}]
```

Now redefine it with:

```
In [6]: dummy_function = conf_deco(dummy_function)
```

and it'll only return the confidence value

```
In [7]: dummy_function("something", kw='else')
('something',) {'kw': 'else'}
Out[7]: 0.32
```

Comment: Hey @Scott Staniewicz Thanks for the quick reply. The first code returns "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" . So i change to "return out[0]" which returned {'label': 'Carrr', 'confidence': 0.32647023, 'topleft': {'x': 98, 'y': 249}, 'bottomright': {'x': 311, 'y': 455}} but all in a new line. So now i need to access only the second line to get confidence. I have not tried making a decorator tho. Sadly can only do it on Monday. But in any case will let you know

Comment: Oh I see that the output you posted is a dict contained in a list- i edited the answer accordingly